# Google app engine first daily connection fail

Tags: java, web-services, google-app-engine

I've notice a strange behavior of google app engine. I've a SOAP webservice load on it, and a servlet as a client. Everyday, after my appengine quotase are resetted (i use a free account), first attempt of client to connect to webservice fail, and after a manual refresh, everithing works fine until next day. on client i have this error:

```
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$FieldReflection <init>: Unable to make javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference.address accessible.
```

Why? it's an appengine bug?

Comment: Does your application have a long startup time (longer than the SOAP timeout)?

Comment: i don't think so. I've write client and server by following the official tutorial on google developers. I've just add a service that retrieve data from datastore, but this shouldn't be the problem.  first execution fail also for the other operations that require less time

Comment: This sounds like a timeout while your app is being spun up on a new server. Have you configured it according to [Google's warmup guidelines](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Java_appengine_web_xml_Warmup_requests)?

Comment: mmm no :) now i read that link. Thanks in advice